# Need help with 57:25

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, quran-translation

يَعلَمَ is translated as a thing like "and will make evident Allah". What is the basis of this translation? how can Allah learn if he knows everything? why did it not use يُ as in 24:31?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please share all relevant information you neither quoted the verse nor the source of your translation. As is written you expect from us to do more effort than you've done to post your two lines without knowing what you are referring to. For further information about our site and model consider taking the  [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about: Elaborate your question by adding all necessary information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabari says in his tafsir of ⟪And We did not make the qiblah which you used to face except that We might know who would follow the Messenger from who would turn back on his heels.⟫ (2:143):

> If a person asks: Was Allah not knowledgeable of who follows the
> messenger and those who turn away on their heels until after the
> follower followed and the turner turned? Because He said, "We did not
> do this action of changing the qiblah except so We know the followers
> of the Messenger of Allah and those who turn away."
>
> It would be said: Allah knows everything before it existed, and the
> statement ⟪And We did not make the qiblah which you used to face
> except that We might know who would follow the Messenger from who
> would turn back on his heels⟫ does not indicate that He did not know
> before it happened.
>
> If he asks: What does it mean then?
>
> It would be said to him: As for the meaning according to us, it is
> that We did not make the qiblah they were on except so that my
> Messenger, my party, and my allies would know who follows the Prophet
> and who turns away. Allah said ⟪So that We may know⟫ to mean "so that
> my Messenger and allies know" since the messenger and His allies are
> from His group and it was a way of speaking for the Arabs that they
> would grammatically attribute an action done by the followers of a
> leader to the leader and vice versa. For example, they can say "Umar
> ibn Al-Khattab conquered Iraq" when in actuality his companions did
> that due to his commands. Another example is what was narrated from
> the Prophet (SAW) saying, "Allah has said, 'I was sick and my slave
> did not visit me. I asked for a loan and he did not give me a loan. He
> cursed me and he had no right to curse me.'"
>
> ٢٢٠٦- حدثنا أبو كريب قال، حدثنا خالد، عن محمد بن جعفر، عن العلاء بن
> عبد الرحمن، عن أبيه، عن أبي هريرة قال: قال رسول الله ﷺ: قالَ الله:
> استقرضتُ عَبدي فلم يُقرضني، وشتمني ولم يَنبغ له أن يشتُمني! يقول:
> وادَهراه! وأنا الدهر، أنا الدهر.
>
> 2206. Abu Hurairah (RA) narrated that the Messenger of Allah said: Allah said: I asked for a loan from my slave and he did not give it to
>       me. He cursed me, and he had no right to curse me. He said
>       'waadahraah' ("Curse the time!"), and I am time. I am time.
>
> ٢٢٠٧- حدثنا ابن حميد قال، حدثنا سلمة، عن ابن إسحاق، عن العلاء بن عبد
> الرحمن، عن أبيه، عن أبي هريرة، عن النبي ﷺ بنحوه.
>
> 2207. Another isnad for the same narration.
>
> (See similar narration in Sahih Muslim)
>
> So, Allah grammatically attributed asking for a loan and visiting to
> Himself, but it is rather referring to someone other than Him who is
> under His command.
>
> It has been narrated from the Arabs that they say, "I am hungry but
> not in my stomach. I am clotheless but not on my body" with the
> meaning of: my family and relatives are hungry and clotheless.
>
> This is how the statement ⟪Except so We may know⟫ means: so my allies
> and group know.
>
> The people of interpretation said similar to what we have said.
>
> List of those who said it:
>
> ٢٢٠٨- حدثني المثنى قال، حدثنا أبو صالح قال، حدثني معاوية بن صالح، عن
> علي بن أبي طلحة، عن ابن عباس:"وما جَعلنا القبلةَ التي كنت عليها إلا
> لنعلم من يتّبع الرسول ممن ينقلب على عقبيه"، قال ابن عباس: لنميّز أهلَ
> اليقين من أهل الشرك والريبة.
>
> 2207. According to Ibn Abbas (RA) ⟪And We did not make the qiblah which you used to face except that We might know who would follow the
>       Messenger from who would turn back on his heels⟫ means: So that we
>       separate the people of certainty from the people of shirk and doubts.

That is why the phrase ⟪so that Allah knows⟫ means so that the thing becomes evident and people know.

The reason Allah phrases it like this rather than making it explicit is to emphasize how important this issue of separation and making evident is. It is so important that Allah attributed the verb to Himself.

As for verse 24:73, the knowledge in that verse is bad and there is no reason to make it important. People need to stop that from being evident, so why would you emphasize it by attributing it to Allah??

Comment: Now that I think about it, it seems like pretty acceptable. But how do you justify it for an already all knowing being?

Comment: @Vbscript The quote from Tabari is entirely about that.